# Generate particles around the outline of a shape with SKEmitterNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skemitternode

From the documentation I read, SKEmitterNode's particle field is rectangular and can be adjusted using `particlePosition` and `particlePositionRange`.

If I want to have particles being emitted around a shape, like an outline of a circle, is there a way to do that? Or is the best way just placing a series of SKEmitterNode around the circle?

Comment: I think you can do only the secon way